# Can I inherit user defined environment variables from the iOS App in a WatchKit app?

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, xcode-6.2

I have a project with multiple targets. Each target has a user-defined build setting named `$(BUNDLE_ID)` to set the bundle ID of that target - of course this setting must be per-target, not for the whole project.

Now for the WatchKit Apps, I need to have multiple WatchKit targets (two for each iOS App target), and each of those uses `$(PARENT_BUNDLE_ID)` for convenience and ability to share Info.plist etc. between multiple targets.

Currently the `$(PARENT_BUNDLE_ID)` needs to be set twice (Once in the WatchKit App target and once in the WatchKit Extension target). What I would like to do is specify it zero times for the WatchKit components, and somehow inherit/copy it from the `$(BUNDLE_ID)` of the iOS App target in which it is embedded. Is this possible, and how can I set it up in Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It can be done. In order to have a bundle identifier which can be accessible to all your target, you need to define that bundle identifier into project setting as user defined keys and assigned a value to it.

Once you define key "Bundle_ID" into project setting, the key "Bundle_ID" will reflect into all your target which are associated with that project setting.

[image: Project Setting]
 You can access these key using $(Bundle_ID) into plist for all your targets, as explain into image below.

[image: Plist and target will reflect user defined value]

Comment: I think you missed the part of the question where I mentioned that I have multiple targets and therefore the `BUNDLE_ID` for them all can't be set in the *project* build settings (which are as you say inherited by all targets), and must be set in the build settings for each individual *target*.

Comment: You can create a PARENT_BUNDLE_ID and derived your target BUNDLE ID based on your PARENT_BUNDLE_ID which is defined in to project setting.

Comment: I have 8 targets for iOSApps - they all have different bundle IDs of course, as they are distinct apps on the App-Store. Therefore the setting must be defined in each *target* not the *project*... so I'd like the 8 WatchKit apps/extensions to have access to the ID from the target they are embedded in (i.e. another target, not the project).

Comment: You can define 8 keys in the project setting like 'Bundle_ID_ProjectA', This implementation allows you to change bundle id in one place and it reflect those over all the places where you are using those id.